# add white border around active page in navigation menu

Tags: html, css

Im working on a navigation menu on my site and I want to make it so there will be a 1px solid white border around the button of the current page, so for example if I'm on the about page, there will be a white border around the about button.
I have already made this for the hovering, now I just need someone to help me do that on the current page as I described above.

edit: I forgot to mention that the html code is taken from my master page, so I don't have this code on each one of the pages. is there a way to still do it?

this is what I did for the hover(which works just like I wanted it to work):

```
.main-nav li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #266EB8;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

and this is my html:

```
<header>
   <div class="row">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="HomePage.aspx">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="GalleryPage.aspx">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="AboutPage.aspx">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="RegistrationPage.aspx">REGISTRATION</a></li>
        <li><a href="ContactUsPage.aspx">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

hope that you understood me.

Comment: Have you tried using JavaScript?

Comment: @Gendarme
not really an expert in js, I started coding in html a few days ago and im learning on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to move the active class down to the anchor that is the current page. i.e for About it would be:

```css
body {
  background-color: #AAA;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav .active a {
  background: white;
  color: #266eb8;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="HomePage.aspx">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="GalleryPage.aspx">GALLERY</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="AboutPage.aspx">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="RegistrationPage.aspx">REGISTRATION</a></li>
      <li><a href="ContactUsPage.aspx">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the html code is taken from my master page, so I don't have this code on each one of the pages.
is there a way to still do it?